# Return child objects from a JObject based on property value

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have some JSON as shown below.  I would like to get all objects from it where the "type" is "Item".

```
 string json = @"
        {
            'name': 'Object 1',
            'content': {
                'body': {
                    'id': 'body',
                    'type': 'Body'
                },
                'style': {
                    'id': 'style',
                    'type': 'Style'
                },
                'DynamicName-123': {
                    'id': 'DynamicName-123',
                    'type': 'Row'
                },
                'DynamicName-434': {
                    'id': 'DynamicName-434',
                    'type': 'Column'
                },
                'DynamicName-223': {
                    'id': 'DynamicName-223',
                    'type': 'Item'
                }
            }
        }";

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Expected output:

```
'id': 'DynamicName-223',
'type': 'Item'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the objects that have  a "type" property value of "Item" using a [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) query like this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

List<JObject> items = obj["content"]
    .Children<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => (string)p.Value["type"] == "Item")
    .Select(p => (JObject)p.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dy1nQC

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that I saw some of the post you did on the other threads you have some great knowledge in JSON.net! Can I ask you on more question. I have a property on the column object called parentId which holds row object id. As you know a row can have multiple columns. How can both return a row and all colmuns linked to that row id so I can keep parent/child relationship?

Comment: @Mask-dCodex -- Aleks Andreev just answered that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55635592/10263).

Comment: Brian, are you able to advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize to anonymous type with Dictionary inside:

```
var template = new {name = "", content = new Dictionary<string, JObject>()};
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, template);
```

Now you can get all info from nested items:

```
foreach (var item in result.content)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: id = {item.Value["id"]}, type = {item.Value["type"]}");
```

Output will be:

> body: id = body, type = Body
>   style: id = style, type = Style
>   DynamicName-123: id = DynamicName-123, type = Row
>   DynamicName-434: id = DynamicName-434, type = Column
>   DynamicName-223: id = DynamicName-223, type = Item

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know there are quick ways to filter it however I am looking to expand my filtering method to accomplish this :). I have deserialized it like this: JObject obj= JObject.Parse(json);