# Dictionary<string, JToken> recursive search

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have DeserializeObject to a C# object however I have objects with dynamic object names so I have structured it like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public TableLayout table{ get; set; }
}

public class TableLayout 
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; } //Static
    public Info info { get; set; } //Static
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> item { get; set; }
}
```

So basically any dynamic objects that appear will be added to the dictionary and using JsonExtensionData will populate the rest of the property without creating the object classes. Here is my json:

```
string json = @"
            {
            "name": "Table 100",
            "table": {
                "attributes ": {
                    "id": "attributes",
                    "type": "attributes"
                },
                "info": {
                    "id": "info",
                    "type": "info"
                },
                "item-id12": {
                    "id": "item-id12",
                    "type": "Row"
                    "index": 0
                },
                "item-id16": {
                    "id": "item-id16",
                    "type": "Column"
                    "parentid": "item-id12"
                },
                "item-id21": {
                    "id": "item-id21",
                    "type": "Column",
                    "parentid": "item-id12"
                }
            }
        }";
```

How can I use type ="row" and index value(increments to index 1 to evaluate next row) property to get all columns using parentId of column objects in my Dictionary.

Desired Output:

```
         "item-id12": {
                    "id": "item-id12",
                    "type": "Row"
                    "index": 0
                },
                "item-id16": {
                    "id": "item-id16",
                    "type": "Column"
                    "parentid": "item-id12"
                },
                "item-id21": {
                    "id": "item-id21",
                    "type": "Column",
                    "parentid": "item-id12"
                }
```

Comment: I'm sure I have tried it this way but it did not work. I can access all dictionary by 
rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json). rootobject.table.item but I want to filter it as there are many Row/Column relationship as there are many row objects with multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to find your root object

```
var rootNode = json.table.item.Values
      .FirstOrDefault(x => x["type"].Value<string>() == "Row" && x["index"].Value<int>() == 0);

if (rootNode == null)
    return; // no such item
```

Now if this item exists use linq again and get all items from dictionary:

```
var childNodes = json.table.item.Values
      .Where(x => x["parentid"]?.Value<string>() == rootNode["id"].Value<string>());
```

Next code

```
var output = new[] {rootNode}.Concat(childNodes);
foreach (var item in output)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

will print

```
{
  "id": "item-id12",
  "type": "Row",
  "index": 0
}
{
  "id": "item-id16",
  "type": "Column",
  "parentid": "item-id12"
}
{
  "id": "item-id21",
  "type": "Column",
  "parentid": "item-id12"
}
```

P.S. Your input json is invalid, it missing few commas

Comment: Ah I did not know Linq can be used to access properties! This would only access index 0, how can I create a loop so that it increments index until all rows and related columns are found as there can be index x in the unordered json list. Would add the code within a while loop and look at the property index?

Comment: @JustMeCOdex You can put search for root element into loop and modify search query to `x["index"].Value<int>() == i` where `i` would be increment in cycle. If this comment does not help I think you should create a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide JSON you have with more rows, your current code and expected output